# Quaternion-Vector transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, quaternions

I have the following problem:

Rotations can be done by using quaternions. My understanding is, that to rotate a vector around a quaternion, the vector has to be transformed to a 4-dimensional vector: **v = [x,y,z] to v'= [0,x,y,z]**
This vector can now be rotated around the quaternion using **v'2 = q*v'*q'**
where **q'** is the conjugate quaternion and the quaternion product needs to be used.

My problem is, I don't understand how to get a 3D vector from the new, 4-dimensional vector **v'2** since **v'2 = [w,ai,bj,ck]**. Do I just disregard w and use **v_new = [a,b,c]** as my new vector or do I have to do a specific transformation?

Comment: Unless you did something wrong you should automatically have $w=0$ after computing $qv'q'$. But, yes, $v_{new}=(a,b,c)$, where $qv'q'=ai+bj+ck$

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to help! By the way, a namesake of yours is an international level hockey star (originally from the Czech republic). Are you related by any chance :-)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I found out about that when I googled myself but sadly I don't know him :(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jyrki Lahtonen for solving my problem!

If the math is done correctly, the resulting quaternion after **q * v * q'** should have the form **v' = [w, ai, bj, ck]** where **w = 0** and the new vector is **v' = [a,b,c]**